# How to uncheck all radio boxes with same class name but after applying jquery buttonset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is code is working fine for me but only with default HTML radio button controls

```
$('.block1').on("click", function(event){
  $('.block1').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

http://sfiddle.net/bAhmed/zNq9R 
But when I change the default UI of radio buttons by $(".col-lg-4").buttonset();

then the above code is not working for me. As it changes the behavior or applying some other default classes of jquery-ui.css and jquery.js

Ultimate goal is to uncheck all other radio buttons with .block1 class but after applying .buttonset()

Comment: radio buttons, or checkboxes? Your code appears to be unnecessary, since this is how HTML radio buttons behave anyway.

Comment: You are right but just I have a criteria of using different names of radio buttons and with different group and I want them to treat as they are of same name radio buttons. Please check js fiddle link.

Comment: But that defeats the entire purpose of radio buttons in the first place. Give all radio buttons in a group the same name, and unique values. You're trying to fix something that isn't broken, just so you can use it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little difficult to tell what exactly your problem is from the information provided, but it appears to me that your issue may stem from the DOM rearrangement that jQuery UI's `buttonset` function does.

It seems that you were hooking onto `'click'` events fired directly on the radio button input elements previously.  After you call `buttonset()` jQuery UI collapses the input elements on which you registered your click handlers, rendering them unclickable.  So if you want to hook into click events in your buttonset after you call the `buttonset` function, you will have to register the handler on a different set of elements **after** the `buttonset` function has been called.  I would suggest using the label elements created by jQuery UI.  Your code may look something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".col-lg-4")
      .buttonset()
      .find('label.ui-button')
      .on('click', function() {
    $('.block1').prop('checked', false).button('refresh');
    var targetId = '#' + $(this).attr('for');
    $(targetId).prop('checked', true).button('refresh');
  });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please check this code [link]http://jsfiddle.net/bAhmed/zNq9R/ There are two option 1 and 2 and when I select option 1) then option two must be deselected and I am hooked onto assign different names for the radio buttons

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect your more clearly stated question.  Check it out here and tell me if I am understanding you properly: http://jsfiddle.net/zNq9R/6/